# How to factorize calls to ado.net with parameters?

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

i want to factorize all the calls to ado.net present in my web application to not repeat over and over the connection string and the open/close methods. I succeed to do it for the calls without parameter, but i need help for the ones with parameters.

For example, I had :

```
Dim strConnexion As String = "myConnectionString"
Dim strRequete As String = "DELETE FROM tbl_devis WHERE id_devis = " + TBDevis.Text
Dim oConnection As New SqlConnection(strConnexion)
Dim oCommand As New SqlCommand(strRequete, oConnection)
oConnection.Open()
oConnection.ExecuteNonQuery()
oConnection.Close()
```

I factorized it into :

```
ExecuteRequest("DELETE FROM tbl_devis WHERE id_devis = " + TBDevis.Text)
```

And the code of ExecuteRequest :

```
Public Shared Sub ExecuteRequest(ByVal strRequest As String)
    Dim strConnection As String = ChaineDeConnexion()
    Using objConnection = New SqlConnection(strConnection)
        Dim objCommand As SqlCommand
        objCommand = New SqlCommand(strRequest, objConnection)
        objCommand.Connection.Open()
        objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

But I would like be able to pass to Execute request a collection of parameters. This is a very simple example of what kind of code I want to factorize :

```
Dim strConnexion As String = "myConnectionString"
Dim strRequete As String = "DELETE FROM tbl_devis WHERE id_devis = @id_devis"
Dim oConnection As New SqlConnection(strConnexion)
Dim oCommand As New SqlCommand(strRequete, oConnection)
With (myCommand.Parameters)
    .Add(New SqlParameter("@id_devis", SqlDbType.Int))
End With
With myCommand
    .Parameters("@id_devis").Value = TBDevis.Text
End With
oConnection.Open()
oConnection.ExecuteNonQuery()
oConnection.Close()
```

I was thinking about edit my ExecuteRequest function to add an optional parameters collection :

```
Public Shared Sub ExecuteRequest(ByVal strRequest As String, Optional ByRef sqlParameters As SqlParameterCollection = Nothing)
    Dim strConnection As String = ChaineDeConnexion()
    Using objConnection = New SqlConnection(strConnection)
        Dim objCommand As SqlCommand
        objCommand = New SqlCommand(strRequest, objConnection)
        objCommand.Parameters = sqlParameters   'objCommand.Parameters is readonly property
        objCommand.Connection.Open()
        objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

But VS tell me that objCommand.Parameters is a readonly property...

I see two solutions :

- Passing an array containing the parameter name, value and type, and looping through the array
- Creating the string request with all the parameters like that : "DELETE FROM tbl_devis WHERE id_devis = " + TBDevis.Text ... but when there are 30 parameters, this is a dirty solution I guess ?

Which one would be the cleaner, strongest solution please ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ParamArray is what you're looking for.

Update your ExecuteRequest like this:

```
Public Sub ExecuteRequest(ByVal strRequest As String, ParamArray Params() As SqlParameter)
    Dim strConnexion As String = "myConnectionString"
    Using Conn As New SqlConnection(strConnexion), Cmd As New SqlCommand(strRequest, Conn)
        Cmd.Parameters.AddRange(Params)
        Conn.Open()
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

and then you can call it like

```
ExecuteRequest("DELETE FROM tbl_devis WHERE id_devis = @id_devis", New SqlParameter("@id_devis", CInt(TBDevis.Text)))
```

I would also suggest to create function sqlPar(Name As String, Value As Object) with few more overloads to simplify the call to

```
ExecuteRequest("DELETE FROM tbl_devis WHERE id_devis = @id_devis", sqlPar("@id_devis",  TBDevis.Text))
```

ParamArray allows you to add undefined amount of arguments like this

```
ExecuteRequest("SELECT ID FROM Table WHERE ID IN (@A, @B, @C, @D)", sqlPar("@A", 1), sqlPar("@B", 2), sqlPar("@C", 3), sqlPar("@D", 4))
```

You should *ALWAYS* use SqlParameter instead of string concatenation to prevent SQL injections.

You should *ALWAYS* use Using for IDisposable resources as well.